# Pandas dataframe.loc : what does "Boolean list with the same length as the row axis" mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Pandas documentation has this `Boolean list with the same length as the row axis` example, like so:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
...      index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
...      columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
>>> df
            max_speed  shield
cobra               1       2
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8


>>> df.loc[[False, False, True]]
            max_speed  shield
sidewinder          7       8
```

Can someone please explain how the `df.loc[[False, False, True]]` works to get the result shown please?

Thanks.

Comment: `[False, False, True]` directly interprets to row 0=False, row 1=False and row 2=True hence returns the 3rd(2nd since indexing starts at 0) row , in fact i dont think you need `loc` here

Comment: Please also refer docs for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: @anky. Thanks, now I understand.  Could you post it as an answer so I can give you an upvote.  Yup looked at the docs, it does not have explanation of this example.

Comment: zabop has posted an answer that is similar. I guess you should reward their answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[[False,False,True]]` returns the same as `df.loc[[False, False, True]]`.

`df[[False,False,True]]` is more intuitive & can be interpreted as: don't return first & second (ie first & second `False`), return third (ie third is `True`) row.

[In the documentiation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), see the bullet point:

> - A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True].